# Intel 3770K (HD4000) and dual monitor with DVI+VGA

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-14.04

My office computer is running Intel Core i7 3770K (IvyBridge) on an Asus P8H77-V motherboard. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit desktop version).

I've been using an old LG Flatron W2453TQ display (1920x1080) with the setup. When I first got this computer up and running (with Windows 7, nowadays I'm dual-booting to Ubuntu or Win7) the PC had some trouble waking up the DVI-connection from the motherboard to the display (DVI-D). I resorted to plugging in the VGA D-SUB instead and it worked fine.

Now I tried adding another display for the PC (an LG Flatron W2242T, 1650xSomething IIRC).

No matter what combination I try and how many reboots or hot-plugs I do, only the VGA gets any signal out to a display (which means the one in the DVI-end is essentially useless).

The motherboard has 1xDVI, 1xVGA, 1xDP and 1xHDMI outputs, but the monitors I have only accpet 1xDVI-D or 1xVGA D-SUB.

Somewhere I read that using the VGA port might make the display setup go nuts and disable all other ports. Is this the case and should I either get a HDMI/DP to DVI adapter or should I just try with some new monitors? The following discussion states that using the D-SUB is a bit of a no-no: http://www.tonymacx86.com/graphics/83037-hd4000-dual-monitors.html

I have the latest official drivers from Intel and Ubuntu hasn't been configured that much other than installing my work software and so on.